# Redefining theorem breaks nameref

Tags: theorems, amsthm, nameref

I'd like to define a command `\keyifythm{<envname>}` which redefines an amsthm theorem environment to take a key-value optional argument. My approach below works, but for reasons I don't understand it breaks `nameref` support. Here's a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,nameref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { thmkeys/thmuse }
    {
      name .tl_set:N = \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl,
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \keyifythm } { m } {
    \NewEnvironmentCopy { orig-#1 } { #1 }
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { ={name} O{} }
        {
          \keys_set:nn { thmkeys/thmuse } { ##1 }
          \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl
            { \begin{orig-#1} }
            { \begin{orig-#1}[\l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl] }
        }
        {
          \end{orig-#1}
        }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\keyifythm{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[heading] \label{hjk}
Text
\end{theorem}

\ref{hjk}

\begin{theorem}[heading] \label{abc}
Text
\end{theorem}

\nameref{abc} % this fails

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.41 \nameref{abc}
                   % this fails
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

I've determined it's not merely redefining `theorem` that's the issue. For example, replacing `\keyifythm` with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{ \donothingtothm } { m } {
    \NewEnvironmentCopy { orig-#1 } { #1 }
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { o }
        {
          \IfNoValueTF{##1}
            { \begin{orig-#1} }
            { \begin{orig-#1}[##1] }
        }
        {
          \end{orig-#1}
        }
    }
```

works fine with nameref. The issue must be with the way nameref patches the amsthm command `\@begintheorem`, but I don't understand why my redefinition interferes with that. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with amsthm and not much with your redefinition: `nameref` uses the package `gettitlestring` to grab the title and write it into the aux-file and by default this package doesn't expand commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{expand}{gettitlestring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{blub}
\begin{theorem}[\l_tmpa_tl] \label{hjk}
Text
\end{theorem}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\nameref{hjk}

\end{document}
```

will write

```
\newlabel{hjk}{{1}{1}{\l_tmpa_tl }{}{}}
```

into the aux-file, and when this is read back, nameref will not be happy about the underscores.

You can pass the option `expand` to `gettitlestring` then it will expand commands (if there are fragile command you must then protect them). Or you should expands in your definition your variable at least once.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Reading the docs I realized you can also set the `expand` option locally with `\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}`, which is less likely to break usage elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You want to expand (once) the token list variable before LaTeX sees `\begin{orig-...}[...]`.

```
          \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl
            { \begin{orig-#1} }
            { \use:e { \exp_not:N \begin{orig-#1}[ \exp_not:V \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl] } }
```

More cleanly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,nameref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { thmkeys/thmuse }
    {
      name .tl_set:N = \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl,
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \keyifythm } { m } {
    \NewEnvironmentCopy { orig-#1 } { #1 }
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { ={name} O{} }
        {
          \keys_set:nn { thmkeys/thmuse } { ##1 }
          \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl
            { \__thmkeys_begin:n {#1} }
            { \__thmkeys_begin:nV {#1} \l_thmkeys_thmuse_name_tl }
        }
        {
          \end{orig-#1}
        }
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thmkeys_begin:n { \begin{orig-#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__thmkeys_begin:nn { \begin{orig-#1}[#2] }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__thmkeys_begin:nn { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\keyifythm{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[heading] \label{hjk}
Text
\end{theorem}

\ref{hjk}

\begin{theorem}[heading] \label{abc}
Text
\end{theorem}

\nameref{abc} % this fails

\end{document}
```

[image]